# Scroll bar does not work in IE11 with angular-gridster

Tags: jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer-11, gridster

I am using angular-gridster https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster/

Problem can be reproduced with their demo sample. I have just updated first part of demo/main/view.html with this

```
<div gridster="gridsterOpts">
    <ul>
        <li gridster-item="item" ng-repeat="item in standardItems">
            <input type="text" integer ng-model="item.row" size="1" />,
            <input type="text" integer ng-model="item.col" size="1" />
            <br />
            <input type="text" integer ng-model="item.sizeX" size="1" />x
            <input type="text" integer ng-model="item.sizeY" size="1" />

            <div  class="gridster-no-drag" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; overflow: auto;">
                 <table  class="gridster-no-drag" style="width:100%">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Jill</td>
                    <td>Smith</td>
                    <td>50</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Eve</td>
                    <td>Jackson</td>
                    <td>94</td>
                  </tr>
                </table> 
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I enable draggability (with disabled draggability it works) and click the scroll bar. It does not work. This happens in IE11 only.

I have already applied jquery + class="gridster-no-drag". This made gridster work nicer but scroll bar is still not working

How to make scroll bar work?